# Show $\vec{c} \in$ span$(\vec{a}, \vec{b})$ and express $\vec{c}$ as linear combination of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, vectors, systems-of-equations

Given are the vectors
$$\vec{a} = (11, -5, 10, 7)^T$$
$$\vec{b} = (14, -8, 13, 10)^T$$
$$\vec{c} = (19, -13, 18, 15)^T$$

Show that the vector $\vec{c}$ is an element of the vector subspace spanned by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, that is $\vec{c} \in$ span$(\vec{a}, \vec{b})$. Express $\vec{c}$ as linear combination of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

---

Setting up the equations

$$11a + 14b = 19$$
$$-5a - 8b = -13$$
$$10a + 13b = 18$$
$$7a + 10b = 15$$

Using the second and third equations, I get $b = \frac{8}{3}$ and $a = - \frac{5}{3}$

So $-\frac{5}{3} \vec{a} + \frac{8}{3} \vec{b} = \vec{c}$

---

Is that sufficient to show $\vec{c} \in$ span$(\vec{a}, \vec{b})$ and express $\vec{c}$ as linear combination of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ ?

I'm unsure about whether this "proof" is complete, could you give me your opinion and feedback ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why do you think so ? Plugging in the numbers yields in fact $\vec{c} = (19, -13, 18, 15)^T$  or am I missing something ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So is this proof sufficent in your opinion ? Is nothing missing, be it notation or else ? Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If you wish, you can post an answer with potential feedbacks (or also just saying the proof seems good), I will upvote and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from

> Using the second and third equations, I get $b = \frac{8}{3}$ and $a = - \frac{5}{3}$

to

> So $-\frac{5}{3} \vec{a} + \frac{8}{3} \vec{b} = \vec{c}$

is logically incorrect. It does not follow that $-\frac{5}{3} \vec{a} + \frac{8}{3} \vec{b} = \vec{c}$ just from the fact that $a=-\frac53, b=\frac83$ solve the second and third equations.*

Solving the second and third equation tells you only that **if** $a\vec a + b\vec b = \vec c$, **then** $a=-\frac53, b=\frac83$. Now, you have to actually prove that picking $a=-\frac53, b=\frac83$ also guarantees that $a\vec a + b\vec b = \vec c$, and you do that by simply calculating $a\vec a + b\vec b$

---

*For example, if you take $\vec a=(0,1,0,0)^T$, and $\vec b=(0,0,1,0)^T$ and $c=(0,0,0,1)^T$, then the same procedure as you did would yield $a=b=0$, but it should be obvious that $a\vec a + b\vec b\neq \vec c$ in this case.

Comment: "..Now, you have to actually prove that picking $a=−53,b=83$ also guarantees that $a\vec a + b\vec b = \vec c$
 , and you do that by simply calculating $a\vec a + b\vec b = \vec c$"  or one can show that the obtained values of a and b also satisfy first and fourth (hence all) equations.

Comment: So we need to "plug in" the numbers and check if they give us the vector $\vec{c}$ ? Thanks for pointing it out, in fact it makes more sense, didn't think about that

Comment: @wengen Yes, because the implication at first goes only one way. It's "if $a,b$ solve these four equations, then they solve these two equations". And in general, that is not a reverseble line of reasoning.